# Does using jQuery .data() on an element and then removing the element via direct DOM manipulation leak memory

Tags: jquery

I've working on a site that was written using Prototype but we're phasing it to jQuery.  A lot of page updates are done via Prototype's Ajax.Updater. However, sometimes the elements that Prototype removes and replaces have had a jQuery widget run on them, so $.cache has references to the additional elements created by the widget.  Since jQuery isn't doing the DOM removal, it doesn't have a chance to clear the data from $.cache for those elements when they are removed, and I end up with a memory leak.  Is there a way to tell jQuery to check it's $.cache and discard any data for elements that are no longer in the DOM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds a little tricky - particularly since Ajax.Updater is a specialisation of Ajax.Request which does *not* have an onsuccess/oncomplete callback, meaning that you will probably have to do a periodical check of the cache, among other things. That sounds like more work than creating a jQuery 'updater'.

If you are willing to replace the updater with a jQuery rewrite, this problem *completely goes away*, and is certainly simpler than working around it. Simple 'updater' in jQuery follows.

```
function update() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'theContent.html',
        success: function(text) {
            // .html calls '.cleanData()' internally. No need to do anything else.
            $('#updateMe').html(text);
        }
    });
}

var i = setInterval(update, 5000);
```

Comment: Since we're already running a customized version of Prototype to begin with, I just updated the Prototype Object.remove and Object.update functions to use jQuery to remove elements if jQuery is present, thereby guaranteeing data cleanup.  I didn't want to write a jQuery updater because Prototype's Ajax.Updater is used in too many places throughout our code to replace and test fully in a reasonable amount of time.